# How to sort json object and create custom string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, object

how to print following output

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT("Add Date", "%d/%m/%Y"), "-", UCASE("Add By")))
```

From following object

```
"45": {
   "AGGRE_FUN": {
      "GROUP_CONCAT": {
          "priority": 2
      }
   },
   "DATE_TIME_FUN": {
      "DATE_FORMAT": {
          "priority": 0,
          "format": "%d/%m/%Y"
      }
   },
   "STR_FUN": {
       "CONCAT": {
           "priority": 1,
           "value": [46,45],
           "label": ["Add By", "Add Date"],
           "concat_by": "-"
       }
   }
},
"46": {
   "STR_FUN": {
       "UCASE": {
           "priority": 0
       }
   }
}
```

Above given `AGGRE_FUN`, `DATE_TIME_FUN`, `STR_FUN` is static keyword. but inner part is dynamic it should be different depend on user selection

also I have setted `priority` to each function

If any other suggestion please share with me I am creating dynamic query for mysql

Comment: Can you add sample your output?

Comment: they are two objects right ? in some array ?

Comment: I have also written it that GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT("Add Date", "%d/%m/%Y"), "-", UCASE("Add By")))   @TanDuong

Comment: yes @GeorgeBailey